# Jetpack Compose how does SubcomposeLayout work?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As can be seen in [official documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#SubcomposeLayout(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function2)) there is layout named SubcomposeLayout defined as

> Analogue of Layout which allows to subcompose the actual content
> during the measuring stage for example to use the values calculated
> during the measurement as params for the composition of the children.
>
> Possible use cases:
>
> You need to know the constraints passed by the parent during the
> composition and can't solve your use case with just custom Layout or
> LayoutModifier. See
> androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraints.
>
> You want to use the size of one child during the composition of the
> second child.
>
> You want to compose your items lazily based on the available size. For
> example you have a list of 100 items and instead of composing all of
> them you only compose the ones which are currently visible(say 5 of
> them) and compose next items when the component is scrolled.

I searched Stackoverflow with `SubcomposeLayout` keyword but couldn't find anything about it, created this sample code, copied most of it from official document, to test and learn how it works

```
@Composable
private fun SampleContent() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        SubComponent(
            mainContent = {
                Text(
                    "MainContent",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color(0xffF44336))
                        .height(60.dp),
                    color = Color.White
                )
            },
            dependentContent = {
                val size = it

                println(" Dependent size: $size")
                Column() {

                    Text(
                        "Dependent Content",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(Color(0xff9C27B0)),
                        color = Color.White
                    )
                }
            }
        )

    }
}

@Composable
private fun SubComponent(
    mainContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    dependentContent: @Composable (IntSize) -> Unit
) {

    SubcomposeLayout { constraints ->

        val mainPlaceables = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Main, mainContent).map {
            it.measure(constraints)

        }

        val maxSize = mainPlaceables.fold(IntSize.Zero) { currentMax, placeable ->
            IntSize(
                width = maxOf(currentMax.width, placeable.width),
                height = maxOf(currentMax.height, placeable.height)
            )
        }

        layout(maxSize.width, maxSize.height) {

            mainPlaceables.forEach { it.placeRelative(0, 0) }

            subcompose(SlotsEnum.Dependent) {
                dependentContent(maxSize)
            }.forEach {
                it.measure(constraints).placeRelative(0, 0)
            }

        }
    }
}

enum class SlotsEnum { Main, Dependent }
```

It's supposed to re-measure a component based on another component size but what this code actually does is a mystery to me.

1. How does `subcompose` function work?
2. What's the point of `slotId` and can we get slotId in a way?

The description for `subCompose` function

> Performs subcomposition of the provided content with given slotId.
> Params: slotId - unique id which represents the slot we are composing
> into. If you have fixed amount or slots you can use enums as slot ids,
> or if you have a list of items maybe an index in the list or some
> other unique key can work. To be able to correctly match the content
> between remeasures you should provide the object which is equals to
> the one you used during the previous measuring. content - the
> composable content which defines the slot. It could emit multiple
> layouts, in this case the returned list of Measurables will have
> multiple elements.

Can someone explain what it means or/and provide a working sample for `SubcomposeLayout`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> It's supposed to re-measure a component based on another component size...

`SubcomposeLayout` doesn't remeasure. It allows deferring the composition and measure of content until its constraints from its parent are known and some its content can be measured, the results from which and can be passed as a parameter to the deferred content. The above example calculates the maximum size of the content generated by `mainContent` and passes it as a parameter to `deferredContent`. It then measures `deferredContent` and places both `mainContent` and `deferredContent` on top of each other.

The simplest example of how to use `SubcomposeLayout` is  [BoxWithConstraints](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#BoxWithConstraints(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) that just passes the constraints it receives from its parent directly to its content. The constraints of the box are not known until the siblings of the box have been measured by the parent which occurs during layout so the composition of `content` is deferred until layout.

Similarly, for the example above, the `maxSize` of `mainContent` is not known until layout so `deferredContent` is called in layout once `maxSize` is calculated. It always places `deferredContent` on top of `mainContent` so it is assumed that `deferredContent` uses `maxSize` in some way to avoid obscuring the content generated by `mainContent`. Probably not the best design for a composable but the composable was intended to be illustrative not useful itself.

Note that `subcompose` can be called multiple times in the `layout` block. This is, for example, what happens in `LazyRow`. The `slotId` allows `SubcomposeLayout` to track and manage the compositions created by calling `subcompose`. For example, if you are generating the content from an array you might want use the index of the array as its `slotId` allowing `SubcomposeLayout` to determine which `subcompose` generated last time should be used to during recomposition. Also, if a `slotid` is not used any more, `SubcomposeLayout` will dispose its corresponding composition.

As for where the `slotId` goes, that is up to the caller of `SubcomposeLayout`. If the content needs it, pass it as a parameter. The above example doesn't need it as the `slotId` is always the same for `deferredContent` so it doesn't need to go anywhere.

Comment: What if i wanted to use maxSize of not `mainComponent` but max of those 2 `composables`? I need an example to get longest of two composables then setting width of short one same as long one. How can i achieve this with `SubcomposeLayout`?

Comment: _Note that subcompose can be called multiple times in the layout block._ how can this be called? When i call it throws an exception and asks for a new id. And can it only be called inside `layout`block? And does it make any difference for `mainComponent`or `dependentComponent` to call `subcompose` inside or outside of `layout` block?

Comment: Each call to subcompose must have a unique id. It can only be called inside the layout block because it is a call on the LayoutScope receiver.

Comment: _Also, if a slotid is not used any more, SubcomposeLayout will dispose its corresponding composition._ what determines a slotId is not used any  more. Let's say i first measured my composables in my answer below then i increase index and call `subcompose`, does it dispose it's previous composition. If i keep indexes in a list, how does it work then?

Comment: @chuckj may you help me on this one? Is quite similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71502444/compose-two-composables-overlaped-and-constraint-with-them

Comment: Is there a way to get the height size of the highest item inside a LazyRow? I need to make all items the same height, and can't use a layout modifier as I get the max height constraint to be the screen height

Comment: In the future please create a question instead of adding an peripherally related question in a comment.

That said, there isn't and you don't want there to be. To know what the height of the tallest item in a lazy row would require composing and laying out the entire list which is what the LazyRow was designed to avoid. If you want the hight to be fixed you need to come up with a reasonable height and make all rows that height.

Answer (score 9):

I made a sample based on the sample provided by official documents and @chuckj's answer but still not sure if this efficient or right way to implement it.

It basically measures longest component sets parent width  and remeasures shorter one with `minimumWidth` of `Constraint` and resizes short one as can be seen in this gif. This is how whatsapp scales quote and message length basically.

[image]
[image]

Orange and pink containers are Columns, which direct children of `DynamicWidthLayout`, that uses `SubcomposeLayout` to remeasure.

```
@Composable
private fun DynamicWidthLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mainContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    dependentContent: @Composable (IntSize) -> Unit
) {

    SubcomposeLayout(modifier = modifier) { constraints ->


        var mainPlaceables: List<Placeable> = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Main, mainContent).map {
            it.measure(constraints)
        }

        var maxSize =
            mainPlaceables.fold(IntSize.Zero) { currentMax: IntSize, placeable: Placeable ->
                IntSize(
                    width = maxOf(currentMax.width, placeable.width),
                    height = maxOf(currentMax.height, placeable.height)
                )
            }

        val dependentMeasurables: List<Measurable> = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Dependent) {
            //  Send maxSize of mainComponent to
            // dependent composable in case it might be used
            dependentContent(maxSize)
        }

        val dependentPlaceables: List<Placeable> = dependentMeasurables
            .map { measurable: Measurable ->
                measurable.measure(Constraints(maxSize.width, constraints.maxWidth))
            }

        // Get maximum width of dependent composable
        val maxWidth = dependentPlaceables.maxOf { it.width }


        println(" DynamicWidthLayout-> maxSize width: ${maxSize.width}, height: ${maxSize.height}")

        // If width of dependent composable is longer than main one, remeasure main one
        // with dependent composable's width using it as minimumWidthConstraint
        if (maxWidth > maxSize.width) {

            println(" DynamicWidthLayout REMEASURE MAIN COMPONENT")

            // !!!  CANNOT use SlotsEnum.Main here why?
            mainPlaceables = subcompose(2, mainContent).map {
                it.measure(Constraints(maxWidth, constraints.maxWidth))
            }
        }

        // Our final maxSize is longest width and total height of main and dependent composables
        maxSize = IntSize(
            maxSize.width.coerceAtLeast(maxWidth),
            maxSize.height + dependentPlaceables.maxOf { it.height }
        )


        layout(maxSize.width, maxSize.height) {

            // Place layouts
            mainPlaceables.forEach { it.placeRelative(0, 0) }
            dependentPlaceables.forEach {
                it.placeRelative(0, mainPlaceables.maxOf { it.height })
            }
        }
    }
}


enum class SlotsEnum { Main, Dependent }
```

Usage

```
@Composable
private fun TutorialContent() {

    val density = LocalDensity.current.density

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {


        var mainText by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Main Component")) }
        var dependentText by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Dependent Component")) }


        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            value = mainText,
            label = { Text("Main") },
            placeholder = { Text("Set text to change main width") },
            onValueChange = { newValue: TextFieldValue ->
                mainText = newValue
            }
        )

        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            value = dependentText,
            label = { Text("Dependent") },
            placeholder = { Text("Set text to change dependent width") },
            onValueChange = { newValue ->
                dependentText = newValue
            }
        )

        DynamicWidthLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .padding(8.dp),
            mainContent = {

                println(" DynamicWidthLayout-> MainContent {} composed")

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(orange400)
                        .padding(4.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = mainText.text,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(blue400)
                            .height(40.dp),
                        color = Color.White
                    )
                }
            },
            dependentContent = { size: IntSize ->


                //  Measure max width of main component in dp  retrieved
                // by subCompose of dependent component from IntSize
                val maxWidth = with(density) {
                    size.width / this
                }.dp

                println(
                    " DynamicWidthLayout-> DependentContent composed " +
                            "Dependent size: $size, "
                            + "maxWidth: $maxWidth"
                )

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(pink400)
                        .padding(4.dp)
                ) {

                    Text(
                        text = dependentText.text,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(green400),
                        color = Color.White
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And full source code is [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter3_layout/Tutorial3_5SubcomposeLayout.kt).

Comment: Visual aids to new code is always helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Recently i needed to use almost the same SubcomposeLayout in question. I needed a Slider with a Composable thumb that i needed to get its width so i can set start and end of track and full width of Slider i was getting from BoxWithConstraints.

```
enum class SlotsEnum {
    Slider, Thumb
}

/**
 * [SubcomposeLayout] that measure [thumb] size to set Slider's track start and track width.
 * @param thumb thumb Composable
 * @param slider Slider composable that contains **thumb** and **track** of this Slider.
 */
@Composable
private fun SliderComposeLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    thumb: @Composable () -> Unit,
    slider: @Composable (IntSize, Constraints) -> Unit
) {
    SubcomposeLayout(modifier = modifier) { constraints: Constraints ->

        // Subcompose(compose only a section) main content and get Placeable
        val thumbPlaceable: Placeable = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Thumb, thumb).map {
            it.measure(constraints)
        }.first()

        // Width and height of the thumb Composable
        val thumbSize = IntSize(thumbPlaceable.width, thumbPlaceable.height)

        // Whole Slider Composable
        val sliderPlaceable: Placeable = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Slider) {
            slider(thumbSize, constraints)
        }.map {
            it.measure(constraints)
        }.first()


        val sliderWidth = sliderPlaceable.width
        val sliderHeight = sliderPlaceable.height

        layout(sliderWidth, sliderHeight) {
            sliderPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Measured thumb and send its dimensions as IntSize and Constraints to Slider, and only placed Slider since thumb is already placed insider Slider, placing here creates two thumbs.

And used it as

```
    SliderComposeLayout(
        modifier = modifier
            .minimumTouchTargetSize()
            .requiredSizeIn(
                minWidth = ThumbRadius * 2,
                minHeight = ThumbRadius * 2,
            ),
        thumb = { thumb() }
    ) { thumbSize: IntSize, constraints: Constraints ->

        val isRtl = LocalLayoutDirection.current == LayoutDirection.Rtl

        val width = constraints.maxWidth.toFloat()
        val thumbRadiusInPx = (thumbSize.width / 2).toFloat()

        // Start of the track used for measuring progress,
        // it's line + radius of cap which is half of height of track
        // to draw this on canvas starting point of line
        // should be at trackStart + trackHeightInPx / 2 while drawing
        val trackStart: Float
        // End of the track that is used for measuring progress
        val trackEnd: Float
        val strokeRadius: Float
        with(LocalDensity.current) {

            strokeRadius = trackHeight.toPx() / 2
            trackStart = thumbRadiusInPx.coerceAtLeast(strokeRadius)
            trackEnd = width - trackStart
        }
    // Rest of the code
}
```

Result

[image]

[Github link](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Colorful-Sliders) for the code