# Recomposition in jetpack compose vs recycle in old ui?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, kotlin-multiplatform

**LazyColumn** and **LazyRow** are replacing for **RecyclerView** in the old UI but when scrolling the item in **RecyclerView** and back to it disappear then recycle to optimization UI.

LazyColumn and LazyRow are doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I found it from [Jetpack Compose basics Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#8)

> Note: LazyColumn doesn't recycle its children like RecyclerView. It
> emits new Composables as you scroll through it and is still
> performant, as emitting Composables is relatively cheap compared to
> instantiating Android Views

After testing, I see that `LazyColumn` just compose visible items. And, by scrolling the invisible items will recompose when it visible again.

Answer (score 0):

LazyColumn uses LazyList which uses LazyLayout and it uses a`SubComposeLayout` to recompose children Composable when required unlike having a Column with `Modifier.verticalScroll()` which composes all of its children Composables.

> Subcomposable has a subocompose function that can be called multiple
> times in the layout block. This is, for example, what happens in
> LazyRow. The slotId allows SubcomposeLayout to track and manage the
> compositions created by calling subcompose. For example, if you are
> generating the content from an array you might want use the index of
> the array as its slotId allowing SubcomposeLayout to determine which
> subcompose generated last time should be used to during recomposition.
> Also, if a slotid is not used any more, SubcomposeLayout will dispose
> its corresponding composition.

You can read full answer about `SubcomposeLayout` by Google developer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69665926/5457853).