# How to change measurement pivot for layouts in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Start point for each layout is 0.0 top left corner. I wanna change start position to get result like that:
[image]

Found just Modifier.graphicsLayer { transformOrigin } which can change layout transformation point from center to other side.
Right now just using Modifier.offset - layout center point coordinates but wonder if there are better way to do this.

Comment: What do you wish to achieve doing this? I did something like this to change touch are to out of bounds of inner Composable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72802650/is-there-a-way-to-increase-a-composable-size-by-chaining-with-another-modifier

Comment: @Thracian just a custom color picker for desktop app. Wanna calculate circle offset from center point. And actually good to know if this type of functionality is exist.