# Get information about size before is drawn in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I want to get the compose height/width before it's drawn into UI screen, does anyone know if it's possible to do that? And if yes, how?

I tried `Modifier.onPlaced { }` but I think it's already drawn into the UI before I do any modification with that information

Comment: You can get exact size of a Compoasble using SubcomposeLayout. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357119/5457853

Comment: Add it as an answer and I'll give you the correct answer, thanks a lot @Thracian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide code i might be able to provide more specific sample of SubcomposeLayout but i use it to measure dimensions of a Composable without triggering recomposition and when BoxWithConstraints is not enough. As in link in comment under some conditions maxWidth or height does not match composable dimensions.

I use it subcompose some section of Composables to pass required dimensions or like building a Slider with dynamic thumb size, chat rows, and so on. I posted several answer about SubcomposeLayout. You can check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663194/jetpack-compose-how-does-subcomposelayout-work?noredirect=1&lq=1) to see some samples

The recent one i use is a sample one with single main and dependent Composables as in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73706182/5457853)

```
@Composable
internal fun DimensionSubcomposeLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mainContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    dependentContent: @Composable (DpSize) -> Unit
) {

    val density = LocalDensity.current
    SubcomposeLayout(
        modifier = modifier
    ) { constraints: Constraints ->

        // Subcompose(compose only a section) main content and get Placeable
        val mainPlaceable: Placeable = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Main, mainContent)
            .map {
                it.measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0))
            }.first()


        val dependentPlaceable: Placeable =
            subcompose(SlotsEnum.Dependent) {
                dependentContent(
                    DpSize(
                        density.run { mainPlaceable.width.toDp() },
                        density.run { mainPlaceable.height.toDp() }
                    )
                )
            }
                .map { measurable: Measurable ->
                    measurable.measure(constraints)
                }.first()


        layout(mainPlaceable.width, mainPlaceable.height) {
            dependentPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Enum class for SubcomposeLayouts with main and dependent Composables
 */
enum class SlotsEnum { Main, Dependent }
```

Passing a Composable as `mainContent` param will return its size in Dp without recomposition for `dependentContent`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is more than enough and I appreciate the time on helping me, now I know a lot of use cases that I can use subcompose layout for :D

Comment: It's used in other Composables such as Scaffold, TabRow, ScrollableTabRow, BoxWithConstraints, BackdropScaffold, LookAheadLayout and LazyLists. It has very wide use cases.