# Calculate size of content without rendering

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I would like to know the size of a Composable without rendering it.

Use case: I have some content inside an `AnimatedVisibility` with `visible = false`, so it is not rendered. I would like to know the width of its content without rendering it so that its container can be properly sized, and will "open" vertically when `visible` becomes `true` without having its width "jump".

Ideally, I would like something like:

```kotlin
val width = remember { measureContent { MyContent() } }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(width)
        // Lots of other modifiers...
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = opened) {
        MyContent()
    }
}
```

Is that doable?

Comment: You can check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354911/how-to-get-exact-size-without-recomposition/73357119#73357119 Using `SubcomposeLayout` you can defer composition phase  after layout and measurement.

Comment: In you case you can do it with `Layout` as well. Create 2 slots measure `MyContent` and set Layout dimensions and slot that contains `AnimatedVisibility` will measured with MyContent dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is not directly possible. The size of a Composable is typically calculated during the **layout phase, which involves measuring and positioning** the composable elements within the UI hierarchy.
**Rendering**, on the other hand, is the process of **drawing the composables onto the
screen**.

As far as I know, it's possible to query the size of a composable *after it has been measured and laid out* with `onGloballyPositioned` modifier like this :

```
Modifier
    .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
        size = coordinates.size
    }
```

Comment: Hi ucMedia. You can defer composition phase after layout using `SubcomposeLayout`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69665926/5457853. Using a MutableState inside Modifier.globallyPositioned/onSizeChanged/onPlaced to set size triggers recomposition so it's not good in cases where you see a jump due to size change

Comment: Hi @Thracian , absolutely, So right

Comment: The answer above explains it very well but it's a bit complicated. It took lots of time to understand what he meant. It basically calls composition of child composables when you call `subcompose` function and thanks to that you can pass any param before child recomposition because in layout phase of parent you can get some values via measurement of measurables